# Moving a directory in java throws java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException

Tags: java, windows

I am creating a rollback feature and here is what I have and wanna achieve:

1. a `tmp folder` is created in the same location as the `data folder`;
2. before doing any operation I copy all the contents from `data folder` to `tmp folder` (small amount of data).
3. On rollback I want to delete the `data folder` and **rename** `tmp folder` to `data folder`.

This is what I tried

```
String contentPath = "c:\\temp\\data";
    String tmpContentPath = "c:\\temp\\data.TMP";
    if (Files.exists(Paths.get(tmpContentPath)) && Files.list(Paths.get(tmpContentPath)).count() > 0) {
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(contentPath));
        Files.move(Paths.get(tmpContentPath), Paths.get(contentPath), java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
```

but this throws `FileAlreadyExistsException` even though I deleted the target directory in the same method.

Once the program exits I don't see the `c:\temp\data` directory, so the directory is actually deleted.

Now if I try StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE it throws an java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException.

What is the best way to move `tmp dir` to `data dir` in these kind of situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. In my code before doing a rollback, I am doing a backup, in that method I am using this section to do the copy

```
if (Files.exists(Paths.get(contentPath)) && Files.list(Paths.get(contentPath)).count() > 0) {
        copyPath(Paths.get(contentPath), Paths.get(tmpContentPath));
```

}

Changed it to

```
try (Stream<Path> fileList = Files.list(Paths.get(contentPath))) {
        if (Files.exists(Paths.get(contentPath)) && fileList.count() > 0) {
            copyPath(Paths.get(contentPath), Paths.get(tmpContentPath));
        }
    }
```

to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Actually in java 7 or above you can just use the [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) to achieve the folder moving even there is a **conflict**, which means the target folder already exists.

```
private static void moveFolder(Path thePath, Path targetPath) {
    if (Files.exists(targetPath)) { // if the target folder exists, delete it first;
        deleteFolder(targetPath);
    }
    try {
        Files.move(thePath, targetPath);
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
        ignored.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void deleteFolder(Path path) {
    try {
        if (Files.isRegularFile(path)) { // delete regular file directly;
            Files.delete(path);
            return;
        }
        try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(path)) {
            paths.filter(p -> p.compareTo(path) != 0).forEach(p -> deleteFolder(p)); // delete all the children folders or files;
            Files.delete(path); // delete the folder itself;
        }
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
        ignored.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: ,thanks for the response. If you look at my code , iam already using Files.move

Comment: @gechu I edited your question for U. I checked your code. In your code, the **existed** directory stopped your moving, so in my solution I deleted it using pure java code which works. So might I ask what's your concern here?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tested your code on my system. It still does not work for me. I still get java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException. Infact I also tried to delete the folder using Files.walkFileTree method and it also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This
public class MoveFolder
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    File sourceFolder = new File("c:\\temp\\data.TMP");
    File destinationFolder = new File("c:\\temp\\data");
    if (destinationFolder.exists())
    {
        destinationFolder.delete();
    }
    copyAllData(sourceFolder, destinationFolder);
}
private static void copyAllData(File sourceFolder, File destinationFolder) 
throws IOException
{
       destinationFolder.mkdir();
       String files[] = sourceFolder.list();
       for (String file : files)
        {
            File srcFile = new File(sourceFolder, file);
            File destFile = new File(destinationFolder, file);
            copyAllData(srcFile, destFile);  //call recursive
        }
}
}
```